# separate meaningful words from text file using C# or any open source text mining API

Tags: c#, text, text-mining

I am working on a video processing project in which i extract text from video given as input and save that text in a text file.I have the text which has garbage text as well as words , i now need to separate out meaningful words from the generated text and convert them into tags?
can anyone suggest API/algorithm that can be use for this ?

Comment: Can you run them through something like http://aspell-net.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Don't you think this will make infinite amount of comparisons to generate words that can be saved as tags ?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) (natural language processing) and the C# derivative [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i need a c# based api for this ,

Comment: SharpNLP... oh that is a thing that actually exists. I'll update my answer. There is also IKVM.NET but I've never had success with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharpNLP with the **SharpEntropy.dll and OpenNLP.dll** for doing this along with the following snippet.

```
private OpenNLP.Tools.Tokenize.EnglishMaximumEntropyTokenizer mTokenizer;
private string[] Tokenize(string text)
{
    if (mTokenizer == null)
    {
        mTokenizer = new OpenNLP.Tools.Tokenize.EnglishMaximumEntropyTokenizer(mModelPath + "EnglishTok.nbin");
    }
    return mTokenizer.Tokenize(text);
}
```

Now you will have a string array of tokens. I mean a string array containing all data. Junk may be included. Now you have to separate only the meaningful tokens. For this you can use the NHunspell.dll

```
public list<string> validate(string[] tokens)
{
      Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_US.aff", "en_US.dic");
      List<string> valid_tokens = new List<string>();
      foreach (string token in tokens)
      {
           if (!hunspell.Spell(token))
           {
                valid_tokens.Add(token);
           }
      }
      hunspell.Dispose();
      return valid_tokens;
}
```

Now you will have a list **valid_tokens** that contain only valid tokens that have a meaning in English. 
Hope this solves your problem.

For a step by step way of integrating SharpNLP into your Visual Studio Project, go though this detailed article that I have written.
[Easy way of Integrating SharpNLP with a Visual Studio C# Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279054/sharpnlp-as-nbin-file-extension/19456965#19456965)